# which section will have security node in App.Config ? or where to add in app.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a app.config for my console application and I want to consume third party webservice.asmx and NOT wcf. The third party has asked to add the following security mode lines but do not where to add in in app.config.

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```